# Multiple Order By clauses in Phantom for Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I had a query using phantom v1.5.0 that had multiple orderBy clauses as the orderBy function took one or more `OrderingCondition`s.

In the update to 1.11.0 (1.8.0 really) the Query API changed to only allow one ordering condition.  When I try to chain `orderBy` on a `SelectQuery` I get the following error on the `SelectQuery` returned by the first `orderBy`:

```
Cannot prove that com.websudos.phantom.builder.Ordered =:= com.websudos.phantom.builder.Unordered
```

Seems obvious that Ordered is not equal to Unordered but also seems to imply that you can only order by one column total.

How does one add multiple `orderBy`s to the new Phantom query API?

Answer (score 2):

This was due to an implementation error in the library itself. The issue has been addressed as of phantom 1.13.0.

The way to specify multiple ordering clauses in a single statement is straightforward:

```
Table.select.where(_.a eqs "test").orderBy(_.col1 asc, _.col2 desc, ..)
```